# Sending a String result to a website

Tags: android

I'm rather new to Android Dev and I'm stuck at the very last part of my app. I've made a barcode scanning app (thanks Zxing) and would like to search the result on a website.

So for example if I wanted to search my result on www.trademe.co.nz how would I go about doing this?

So far I've gotten the String and opened the browser I just don't know how to import the text into the right textbox and search it.

The web part of my code.

```
private void openBrowser(String contents, String format) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://www.trademe.co.nz"));
        startActivity(i);       

}
```

Sorry if I've done something wrong, this is my first post!

Thanks is advanced for any help :)

Comment: http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/SearchResults.aspx?searchType=all&searchString=  "attach your string here"  it uses the get method i hope you can do from there

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (and mark this as an answer if my answer solve your problem)

```
private void openBrowser(String contents, String format) {
String url = "http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/SearchResults.aspx?searchType=all&searchString=%s&rptpath=all&type=Search&generalSearch_keypresses=5&generalSearch_suggested=0";

try
    {
        your_keyword = URLEncoder.encode(your_keyword, "UTF-8")); //encode keyword
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     

    url = String.format(url, your_keyword);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

}

Comment: Cheers! Sorry to ask, but how do I change the questions to solved?

Answer (score 1):

Use httpPost method to post your string to the url.

Check 
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)

Also see a simple example [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)